# How to check if record exist and not duplicate method firstOrCreate laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to use method firstOrCreate laravel in for ex like this

i have try like below, its that okey doing this?

```php
$insert[] = [
   'bulan' => $bulan,
   'tahun' => $tahun,
   'nama_pkp'  => $v["nama_pkp"],
   'keterangan'=> $v["keterangan"],
   'no_faktur_pajak'   => $v["no_faktur_pajak"],
   'tgl_faktur_pajak'  => $tgl_faktur_pajak_format,
   'ref'   => $v["ref"],
   'dpp'   => $v["dpp"],
   'ppn'   => $ppn,
   'invoice_no'=> $v["invoice_no"],
   'nama_tenant'   => $v["nama_tenant"],
   'pph_4_deyon'   => $v["pph_4_deyon"],
   'pph_4_tenant'  => $v["ppn"],
   'no_p_l_tenant' => $v["no_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
   'bukpot_oleh_tenant'=> $v["bukti_potong_oleh_tenant"],
   'tgl_p_l_penyewa'   => $tgl_p_l_penyewa_format,
   'pph_p_l_tenant'=> $v["pph_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
   'note'  => $v["note"],
   'checklist' => $v["checklist"],
   'selisih'   => $selisih,
];

$insertData[] = Data::firstOrCreate($insert);
```

and i have error like this

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version

i have add code AppServiceProvider

```php
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're checking all column in the database, this should look more clean and tidy

```
$data = Data::firstOrCreate([
       'bulan' => $bulan,
       'tahun' => $tahun,
       'nama_pkp'  => $v["nama_pkp"],
       'keterangan'=> $v["keterangan"],
       'no_faktur_pajak'   => $v["no_faktur_pajak"],
       'tgl_faktur_pajak'  => $tgl_faktur_pajak_format,
       'ref'   => $v["ref"],
       'dpp'   => $v["dpp"],
       'ppn'   => $ppn,
       'invoice_no'=> $v["invoice_no"],
       'nama_tenant'   => $v["nama_tenant"],
       'pph_4_deyon'   => $v["pph_4_deyon"],
       'pph_4_tenant'  => $v["ppn"],
       'no_p_l_tenant' => $v["no_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
       'bukpot_oleh_tenant'=> $v["bukti_potong_oleh_tenant"],
       'tgl_p_l_penyewa'   => $tgl_p_l_penyewa_format,
       'pph_p_l_tenant'=> $v["pph_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
       'note'  => $v["note"],
       'checklist' => $v["checklist"],
       'selisih'   => $selisih
]);
```

Comment: i have checking my column, its no error and mistake

Answer (score 0):

You've passed multi dimensional array to `firstOrCreate`,

firstOrCreate() checks for all the arguments to be present before it finds a match. If not all arguments match, then a new instance of the model will be created.

If you only want to check on a specific field, then use firstOrCreate(['field_name' => 'value']) with only one item in the array. This will return the first item that matches, or create a new one if not matches are found.

If you're using it inside the loop then
it should be like this

```
foreach ($variable as $v) {
    $insert = [
        'bulan' => $bulan,
        'tahun' => $tahun,
        'nama_pkp'  => $v["nama_pkp"],
        'keterangan'=> $v["keterangan"],
        'no_faktur_pajak'   => $v["no_faktur_pajak"],
        'tgl_faktur_pajak'  => $tgl_faktur_pajak_format,
        'ref'   => $v["ref"],
        'dpp'   => $v["dpp"],
        'ppn'   => $ppn,
        'invoice_no'=> $v["invoice_no"],
        'nama_tenant'   => $v["nama_tenant"],
        'pph_4_deyon'   => $v["pph_4_deyon"],
        'pph_4_tenant'  => $v["ppn"],
        'no_p_l_tenant' => $v["no_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
        'bukpot_oleh_tenant'=> $v["bukti_potong_oleh_tenant"],
        'tgl_p_l_penyewa'   => $tgl_p_l_penyewa_format,
        'pph_p_l_tenant'=> $v["pph_potong_dan_lapor_tenant"],
        'note'  => $v["note"],
        'checklist' => $v["checklist"],
        'selisih'   => $selisih,
    ];

    $insertData[] = Data::firstOrCreate($insert);
}
```

there is no other way rather than to loop over the big array

Comment: var $insert must be array like $insert[] because its in foreach array, if i run your suggest, its only one data will be insert to database

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it and let me know if you need more details